# Neo4j save does not detect removed related item

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am removing one item from a list from a DomainObject after loading. Then I am saving the same object. Which should be deleted the underlying relationship for my domain object to related object. Somehow it does not detect the change but If I use transaction over the whole process it works but not during individual changes. Why is this?
The object state changes for sure but it is not detected via save operation inside neo4j

I am using neo4j ogm 2.1.6

```
DomainOBject{

  list otherObject;

}
```

Smaple code

```
private void updateX(final SomeObect someObect, final SomeData someData) {
    setY(someObect, someData);
    apartmentService.save(someObect);
}

private void setY(final SomeObect someObect, final SomeData someData) {
    someObect.getSpaces().forEach(space -> spaceService.delete(space));
    someObect.getSpaces().clear();
    someData.getSomeListCodes().forEach(code -> {
        if (someotherService.codeIsRelevant(code)) {
            if (someOtherMethodToCheckFIlter(apartment, code)) {
                unitFactory.addBalcony(someObect, DEFAULT_BALCONY_TYPE, code);
                someObectService.save(someObect);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the deletion as a short sample? I tried to reproduce it but it looks ok with 2.1 here.

Comment: this happens if you have the same object being saved multiple times when using the auto-commit and not using transaction on the unit of operation rather to a higher class ..